# Classification with array of strings as input vector

Tags: string, algorithm, hash, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have a question related to the machine learning task. The problem is to predict a value based on the vector of strings. The most straightforward idea that came to mind was to use linear regression. However, since my input is non-numeric, I thought I'd use hashcode of my strings, but I've read somewhere here that the results will be meaningless. Another idea was to encode my strings in base 26 using the letter positions in the alphabet, but I haven't tested it yet, thus asking for advice.

Could someone recommend a good (meaningful) way of encoding strings so that they can be used in linear regression algorithm? Or suggest another machine learning algorithm suitable for the task.

To summarise: the input to the classifier will consist of a fixed size array of strings (arrays are fixed length, not strings), and the output should be an integer in range 0-100. The training data will consist of a collection of such input arrays (x-values) with corresponding numbers (y-values).

Comment: markov chains? If you can't work out the meaning as required byt the assignment, how will you implement something useful?

Comment: thanks for your reply. It's not an assignment, it's my own project

Comment: what does this integer value of the output class represent? How does it correlate with the input data?

Comment: the input is a set of keywords extracted from the text, and the value is a score of the text. The idea is to find how the score correlates to the set of keywords in the text. Scores are assigned objectively.

Answer (score 1):

Transform each one of your `M` strings into an `N`-dimensional vector using a vector space model like [word2vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/) or [GloVe](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/). Then concatenate these vectors to one vector with `M*N` components. Optionally normalize each component to e.g. 0-1. You should then be able to run any regression (or classification) algorithm on the result, e.g. logistic regression.

You might also try a clustering approach, where you cluster all the words in your vocabulary into `N` clusters, e.g. with k-means on the word vectors or using [brown clustering](https://github.com/percyliang/brown-cluster). You could then represent each word in your input array with a one hot vector (i.e. `N-1` zeros and a single one at the index of the cluster of that word). Then concatenate them again and run regression on the result.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Considering that I generate a fixed length list of keywords for a collection of documents, would it be sufficient to use bag-of-words approach to encode text as numbers? Since all of my documents are on the same topic, the list of keywords is likely to be similar across them all, thus the generated dictionary will be relatively small

Comment: If the order of your words isn't important, then bag of words seems like a good first choice to try. You might also take a look at [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) then (i.e. give a keyword more weighting if it appears in a document and appears rarely in other documents).

Answer (score 1):

I did the similar project with strings. I am suggesting one of the way you can implement it. 
In machine learning "naive bayes classifier" will make your problem easy. That works on the probability theory. So if you are working with python there is NLTK(toolkit) and Textblob(library on NLTK), those will help you a lot.
Your question is very generic so I can't describe everything here but just feel free to ask anything you are struggling with, I would be happy to answer them.